# How do I add additional JSON pairs in RAD Studio/Delphi in conjunction with FDBatchMoveJsonWriter?

Tags: json, rest, delphi, session, firedac

I'm using an HTML client, and have the following situation:
Using Embarcadero's RAD Server's built-in method for authentication, I have successfully logged in a user and  would like to now pass the session token back and forth in such a fashion that the connection is RESTful.  The problem lies in the fact that for some reason, I have no clue as to how to track said session token within RAD Server.  Embarcadero themselves have been secretive, telling our company that we can do it with Sencha/ExtJS, but we'd prefer not to have to buy even more software.  The overall structure is as follows:

Login POSTs username and password (working) to RAD Server (still working) and receives response complete with session token.  At this point, I want to open up another HTML file and maintain that session token AS I show data, such that with every JSON request, I send that session token.  But in RAD Studio, as far as I can tell, I cannot manually add JSON data to an already-constructed JSON object to feed to the FDBatchMoveJsonWriter component.  Any suggestions/examples anyone has done regarding this, if it is even possible?

Answer (score 0):

I've not yet used RAD Server, but post to many REST services.  Might RAD Server support Authentication additions in the header?  I connect a THTTPBasicAuthenticator to my TRESTClient and in the OnAuthenticate event add token data.

```
procedure TCLTSProcessor.RESTAuthenticatorAuthenticate(ARequest: TCustomRESTRequest; var ADone: Boolean);
begin
  ARequest.AddAuthParameter('token', userToken, pkHTTPHEADER);
end;
```

Another method I use is connecting a TOAuth2Authenticator to the REST client and set the TokenType to ttBEARER and set the AccessToken property.

Comment: We are using the built-in authentication system